# Processing: library issue?

Tags: processing

I am having trouble possible for my graphics card driver. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and my graphics card model is ATI Mobility™ Radeon® HD 5650 . When i try to execute this simple program

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
size(200, 200, P2D);
myMovie = new Movie(this, "sample_iTunes.mov");
}

void draw() {
image(myMovie, 0, 0);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
m.read();
}

void mousePressed() {
myMovie.play();
}
```

which i didn't modified i got following error.

```
> Smooth level 2 is not available. Using 1 instead
X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: false, open (no close attempt): 3/3, reusable   
(open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 3)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 3
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7099adc0, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
X11Util: Open[1]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x71d17fb0, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
X11Util: Open[2]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x71d1fd40, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load movie     
file sample_iTunes.mov
at processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:3885)
at processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:3894)
at processing.video.Movie.initGStreamer(Movie.java:605)
at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Movie.java:98)
at video.setup(video.java:25)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2241)
at processing.opengl.PGL$PGLListener.display(PGL.java:3240)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:573)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:558)
at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:286)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1021)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:896)
at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:545)
at 

    jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase.defaultWindowRepaintOp(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:106)
at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.access$000(GLWindow.java:94)
at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow$1.windowRepaint(GLWindow.java:107)
at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.consumeWindowEvent(WindowImpl.java:2433)
at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.consumeEvent(WindowImpl.java:1946)
at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.doEvent(WindowImpl.java:1894)
at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.windowRepaint(WindowImpl.java:2626)
at jogamp.newt.WindowImpl.windowRepaint(WindowImpl.java:2610)
at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.windowRepaint(GLWindow.java:591)
at com.jogamp.newt.awt.NewtCanvasAWT.paint(NewtCanvasAWT.java:521)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:248)
at sun.awt.X11.XRepaintArea.paintComponent(XRepaintArea.java:56)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:224)
at sun.awt.X11.XComponentPeer.handleEvent(XComponentPeer.java:677)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4736)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:668)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at 

    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.
    doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.
    doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:641)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:639)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.
    doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:638)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
    X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 3/3,  
    reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 3)
    X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 3
    X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x7099adc0, refCount 1, unCloseable false]

     X11Util: Open[1]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x71d17fb0, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
     X11Util: Open[2]: NamedX11Display[:0, 0x71d1fd40, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
```

What went wrong with this ??

Comment: Have you tried other video encodings? What Processing version do you have? It seems Processing 2 has some problems with video. See: http://forum.processing.org/topic/video-file-lost-in-processing-2-please-help

Comment: @muktoshuvro Can you open the same file with gsvideo alone ? Also, have you tried using Processing 1.5.1 ?

Comment: ok i figured it out...it was due to my graphics card issue...i am able use to play video with vga through given video class in processing though gstream failed due to graphics card issue. I think it supports NVidia.